# How do I open the Disk Utility in Unity?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, disk, gnome-disk-utility

I am new to Ubuntu and have installed it side by side with windows 7. Both boot up okay, my problem is I can't get to disk utility to create a partition that I can share between both OSs. Help says go to activities -> overview and select disk utility there. I can't find activities.

Comment: Is your question "How to create a partition" or "How to find disk utility"?

Answer (score 19):

### Accessing Disk Utility:

I'm sorry you have encountered this level of confusion. Help is referring to the activities overlay that is in GNOME Shell, but you are most likely using Ubuntu's Unity Desktop. Since both are "Shells" for GNOME, the help can overlap sometimes.

What you need to do is open the Unity Dash (it's the button with the Ubuntu logo on the upper left), and type Disk Utility.

[image: Dash the rabbit...]

### Gparted:

However, as Bruno [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/a/86726/1992), you need to install Gparted to actually create partitions with a GUI.

To do this, open the Software Center, search for Gparted, and click install. (Or click this icon: [gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted) [image: Install gparted])

Answer (score 7):

First make sure you have `gparted` installed. Now, in order to access software using the default Unity interface, either press the Meta key (Windows) or press the Ubuntu logo on the launcher.

[image]

From the Dash Home type `gparted` or `Partition Editor` until the GParted Partition Editor appears in the search results

[image]

From here you can either strike <kbd>Enter</kbd> or use your mouse to click the Partition Editor icon.

Comment: Dont think `gparted` is installed by default.

Comment: That's why there are install instructions :)

Comment: At least you did not get a down-vote before editing the answer :(

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create partitions and move data around you can do that with several tools, the default installed tool `Disk Utility` can be called from the dash by pressing the <kbd>super</kbd> key and looking for *Disk* in the search box.

[image]

For a better utility that allows you to do more with your partitions I recommend `gparted`.

Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and install `gparted`.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

`gparted` is an utility that allows you to create/move/resize partitions around without loosing (hopefully) your data.

After installing it you can just open your dash by pressing the <kbd>super</kbd> key and looking for `gparted`.

[image]

[image]

Remember just one thing, you need to have the disks unmounted while doing stuff on them with `gparted` so you cannot do it on the same disk you boot from (its mounted).

To do it on the disk you boot from you need to use the LiveCD to boot and use the same instructions/program to use it.

Answer (score 5):

Run `gnome-disks` from the terminal for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, in Ubuntu 12.10, the **Disk Utility** is known instead as **Disk** So don't worry yourself searching for Disk Utility as nothing of that sort exists in the Dashboard.

Its rather Disk

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> (<kbd>Windows</kbd>) key to open the Unity Dash. Type `disk`. Now you will see the Disk Utility icon in the search results. Click that icon to open Disk Utility.

Answer (score -1):

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, and it wasn't automatically installed.

I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-install gnome-disk-utility
```

Then in the whisker menu (top left icon), I could type "disks" and there it was.