# How do I get Ubuntu 11.10 to recognize my external drive?

Tags: usb, mac, external-hdd

I have a Seagate external drive that I've used with my Mac (firewire). I've just installed Ubuntu on a new netbook, so I've had to use the USB cable for the drive. When I plug it into the netbook, I get nothing. The system doesn't seem to recognize there is a drive now attached.

How do I find it, and mount it?

Comment: Can you use that USB port on your computer with another device like a USB stick? Does that external hard drive work on another computer?

Comment: Are you sure it's not there? open your home folder and look to the left, there is a tree on the sidebar that lists folders if the drive is registered it will be there as a xGB filesystem under "devices"

Comment: Open your terminal and type 'sudo df -ah' and post the results by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked under disk utility to see if the drive is recognized there?  See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86724/how-do-i-open-the-disk-utility-in-the-unity-desktop-environment) for more info on opening the disk utility.

Answer (score 1):

Troubleshooting steps:

1. Try plugging your EHD (external hard drive) into another USB port.
2. If none of your ports work, try another USB device to check whether the ports work.
3. If all ports work but you cannot use your EHD, look for drivers on manufacturers' website(s).
4. Your EHD cannot be used, again? Really? Reinstall Ubuntu now!!!. If your CD has some defects, try redownloading at http://www.ubuntu.com/ and create a new CD, or mount a virtual CD.