# How do I completely remove Ubuntu from my computer?

Tags: installation, windows-7

I completely removed Windows 7 from my computer and installed a full version of Ubuntu on i.e no partition. I just got my Windows recovery disk and driver disk in the mail and I would like to remove Linux completely and re-install Windows.

Problem is the recovery disk will not boot automatically upon starting up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS/Boot Order so that it will start from the CD-Rom before the Hard Disk?

Comment: Your issue should be resolved by changing the device boot order in your computer BIOS

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be just a question of changing the boot order from within your computer's BIOS. It is probably set to boot from the hard disk before trying the CD drive.

You can try simply changing it but I recommend that you remove the partitions that were created by the Ubuntu installation before installing Windows again. Reason for that is that there is a chance Windows will not list every partition currently on your disk and you will end up with a mix install of Windows and Linux partitions.

Start by booting from the Ubuntu LiveCD, select to **Try Ubuntu** and once on the desktop look for the disk utility from the dash, for that have a look on the following post:

- [How do I open the Disk Utility in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86724/how-do-i-open-the-disk-utility-in-the-unity-desktop-environment)

Once the application is open delete all the partitions on your hard disk and apply the changes.

[image]

Ubuntu will be completely removed from your system by now. You can even try to boot the Windows install without changing the boot order in your BIOS, if your computer cannot find any boot partitions it will try to probably boot from the CD drive.

Reboot with the Windows recovery CD and it should start the Windows installation procedure.

Comment: once you delete the partition is there any way to save the partition table? How one can save the changes?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just change the boot order in your Bios.
2. The recovery tool should have an option to erase everything, every partition, etc. and install Windows back like if the pc was just out of the factory.
3. In most cases, the recovery process will ask you to put the driver disk in the driver at some step. If not, you will have to manually install the drivers from the driver disk after the first startup.