# How can i remove Ubuntu 12.04 completly from my System?

Tags: 12.04, windows-xp, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I completely remove Ubuntu from my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196056/how-do-i-completely-remove-ubuntu-from-my-computer)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 after formatting my computer by removing win xp;
now I want to install windows xp again but I am getting some errors.

I can't create partition; if i created one it says his space is 1003 MB

Comment: This is a question about install **Windows XP**, and should be directed elsewhere. Do you have install disks or a recovery image? ***What was not working, when you tried using Ubuntu 12.04 ?***

Comment: Sir i installed Ubuntu without any error and i formated my computer and want to isntall xp after removing my ubuntu 12.04 when i install xp i couldnt format my hard disk cause there is one partion so i neet to make anew partion with freespace :D and install windows xp

Answer (score 2):

In XP setup, delete the existing ubuntu partition by pressing `d` and then create new partition.

**Be careful while deleting. Take a backup of data if possible.**

Comment: Lol i tried to delet it but it cant deleted :(

Comment: what error is coming up?

Comment: @david6 Sir i installed Ubuntu without any error and i formated my computer and want to isntall xp after removing my ubuntu 12.04 when i install xp i couldnt format my hard disk cause there is one partion so i neet to make anew partion with freespace :D and install windows xp

Comment: there`re errors told me that i cant install xp and i can format my disk :(

Comment: You need to delete. Delete is not same as format.