# How to change Harddrive Partition name

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (dual os windows 7)

Now I have total 2 hard drives. 1st is a system hard drive and having two partitions another is 1tb my work hard drive with no partition.

My system hardrive partitions named with it's size like `157 GB Filesystem`, 293 GB Filesystem` etc. I want to change this name.

[image]

I have tried using `GParted` but it doesn't shows that drive but only `Works` drive and DVD`

[image]

How to change these label? and if can't than how to access on terminal? because if use this

```
cd /157 GB Filesystem
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: new to Ubuntu.. where to find `disk-utility`

Comment: Open Dash, and type Disks.  For more info look at the second answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86724/how-do-i-open-the-disk-utility-in-the-unity-desktop-environment).

Comment: This may also be helpful. [You can type spaces in a terminal command, they just need escape characters or quotes](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=890726)

Comment: Okay I got it but now when I click on `Edit Partition` it is not allowing me to rename the label. It is disabled. Any permission issue? How to get permission

Answer (score 0):

You can't be able to rename a partition's label when it was mounted.

In your case it's `/dev/sda1` ntfs partition which was already unmounted.So right-click on the partition and select Label.

[image]

Give the label name and apply it.

Comment: Okay for others is it safe to unmount and mount it again? Will it keep all data

Comment: yes, unmounting and remounting will keeps the data as it is.But don't try to unmount system partition.