# New Ubuntu installation, dual OSX boot, MISSING OPERATING SYSTEM

Tags: dual-boot

I was wondering if someone could help.

I've got a MacMini running Lion, that I want to dual boot Ubuntu on it.

Id created a Live bootable USB USB Ubuntu Installer for MacOS using UNetbootin Utility.

I've Created a partition on the MacMini
am using rEFInd as my dual boot manager and have got the LIVE USB working
and installed Ubuntu

my gparted info...two 500GB partitions on the mac mini
SDA
/dev/sda1 EFI system partition 200MB
/dev/sda2 Customer hfs+ 465GB
/dev/sda3 Recovery HD hfs+ 620MB
SDB
/dev/sdb1 EFI system partition 200MB
/dev/sdb2 Macintosh HD2 280GB
unallocated
/dev/sdb3 UBUNTU 180GB

installed using the "something else" option
chose my partition ( /de/sdb3 )
selected ext4 journalling filing system
mount point /
Set the Device to boot loader installation to sbd1 
(think this is where I went wrong)

and it went about the install and I got a successful install

Now when I boot up I get two options, to boot to OSX or Linux
but when I choose "boot Linux (Legacy) from EFI
I get the message "missing operating system"

its like the operating system is installed but cannot start

Answer (score 0):

The partition that you installed Linux into was apparently not set as bootable. You need to make the partition active and bootable first, it's a flag that you set for the partition.

If you can start an Ubuntu Live system from USB or CD, then start the [Disk utility](https://askubuntu.com/q/86724/805086), select the partition that you installed Ubuntu on, click on the gears button/icon and then "Edit partition". There's a checkbox to make it bootable. If the partition is set to be bootable, it will have a star attached to it in the graphic representation.